# how could use an Object that contains an array as such?

Tags: java, arrays

so i have been creating a method as System.arraycopy .... from java library, but I had a problem with using the object as an array. The problem here is that arr2 needs an array, but java.lang.Object found.

here is the code:

> ```
> public static void arrayCopy (Object arr1 ,int pos1,Object arr2,int pos2,int limit){
>     for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
>         *arr2[pos2]=arr1[pos1];*
>         pos2++;
>         pos1++;
>     }
> }
> ```

I tried doing it this way:

> ```
> public static void arrayCopy (Object arr1[] ,int pos1,Object arr2[],int pos2,int limit){
>     for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
>         arr2[pos2]=arr1[pos1];
>         pos2++;
>         pos1++;
>     }
> }
> ```

the problem is that the method needs an Object [] so when i want to do this there is an error :

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     int[] a = new int [] {1,2,3};
>     int[] b = new int [] {4,5,6};
>     *arrayCopy(a, 0, b, 0, 3);*
> }
> ```

it says "actual argument int[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[] by method invocation conversion". My question is, how could use the array as such? or What can i do?

Comment: `System.arraycopy` is a native method which presumably casts the `Object`s to the necessary array types, but if you look at `java.util.Arrays` you'll see that it has methods for `Object[]` and for each specific kind of primitive array.

Comment: Does your method need to accept only `int[]` arguments, or any arrays?

Comment: any array, but @Andy Thomas answered the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int[]` is not an `Object[]`.

If you want to implement a method that accepts any type of array, you could use the same signature as `System.arrayCopy()`, and use reflection to pick the appropriate implementation.

```
public static void arrayCopy (Object arr1 ,int pos1,Object arr2,int pos2,int limit){ 
    if ( (arr1 instanceof int[]) && (arr2 instanceof int[]) ) {
        int[] iArr1 = (int[]) arr1;
        int[] iArr2 = (int[]) arr2;
        ...
    }
    else if ( arr1 instanceof long[]) && (arr2 instanceof long[]) ) {
        long[] iArr1 = (long[]) arr1;
        long[] iArr2 = (long[]) arr2;
        ...
    }
    // ... etc.
```

That said, if you want a generic method, it would be worthwhile to consider just using the standard method `System.arrayCopy()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing `int` arrays to `arrayCopy` method so you need to use the argument as `int` array instead of `Object` or `Object` array. Just update your second method signature from

```
public static void arrayCopy (Object arr1[] ,int pos1,Object arr2[],int pos2,int limit){
```

to

```
public static void arrayCopy (int arr1[] ,int pos1,int arr2[],int pos2,int limit){
```

Comment: I believe he is attempting to creating a generic method to copy an array of any type. In your example, it must be an int array.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote the method and is not necessary declare an special implementation for each type of array, i only had to use Object class, because Object class is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass.

so i only did this:

> ```
> public static void arrayCopy (Object arr1 ,int pos1,Object arr2,int pos2,int limit){  
>     if (( arr1 instanceof Object) && (arr2 instanceof Object))  {
>         Object[] oArr1 = (Object[]) arr1;
>         Object[] oArr2 = (Object[]) arr2;
>         for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
>             oArr2 [pos2]=oArr1[pos1];
>             pos2++;
>             pos1++;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```